# Angular route. Problem with route between two view

Tags: angular, routes, router

Hi I'm beginner with Angular and I have a problem with routing in my application. I would like route city with restaurant.

```
{ path: 'city', component: City1Component, children: [
{ path: 'restaurant', component: WenecjaComponent },
] },
```

On result view restaurant is in city view. (Image presents problem):
https://ibb.co/82yW1NR

Shows: localhost:4200/city/restaurant but the restaurant view is displayed in the city view.

router-outlet is in component.html under routerlinks

I would like to move me only to the view of the restaurant after clicking on the card. Cards is a 2 boxes with text. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your image is really not clear, can you annotate it? or may be describe specifically in words?

Comment: https://ibb.co/pjvhDs6   I hope the picture is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have children in your case. You route have to be defined like this :

```
{ path: 'city', component: City1Component },
{ path: 'restaurant', component: WenecjaComponent }
```

And the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on your `app.component.html` is enough.

Just change the link of your card like this `<a [routerLink]="['/restaurant']">` to change from city to restaurant.

---

If you need a relation between city and restaurant. You need to add another component in you route to handle the case `localhost/city/[empty]`.

Like this you will have the routes :

- `localhost/city/[empty]` and
- `localhost/city/restaurant`

To do so, you also need to change the route like this :

```
{
  path: 'city',
  component: City1Component,
  children: [
     { path: '', component: [component to create] },
     { path: 'restaurant', component: WenecjaComponent },
  ]
}
```

For more information: https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Comment: Thanks it works but my url: localhost/restaurant this is correct ? I thought it should look like this: localhost/city/restaurant

Comment: It depends what you try to achieve. If you absolutely want a relation between `city` and `restaurant` or not.

Comment: Yes I want relation between city and restaurant because when I choose a city, I will see what restaurant has relations with it